# Drive v3 API has started erroring for 'in parent' queries

Tags: google-drive-api, google-authentication

I have been querying `/drive/v3/files?corpus=domain&spaces=drive&q=...` for a while and everything has been fine. The query looks for a folder, inside a parent folder:

```
name = 'SomeFolder' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'ParentFolder' in parents
```

Just today it, and other queryies I make with 'in parents' have started failing with a 500: `InternalError`. Requests are being made with the current logged-in user's authorization. I get the same result in the query explorer.

Only thing I can think of is that `ParentFolder` has gotten too big, or this is just an InternalError and it will go away.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of a 500 error is an internal timeout within Drive's distributed infrastructure. Unfortunately there are two very different causes for these timeouts, with very different mitigations.

The timeouts might be caused by a temporary issue within the infrastructure. For example a data centre or networking issue. These can sometimes be retried using an exponential backoff, but ymmv. You might just need to wait until the incident is resolved.

Secondly, they may be caused by your request simply causing Drive to do too much work. In this case, a retry is unlikely to make any difference. Try:-

1. Phrasing your query differently. Eg query all folders and then filter on the client for parent and/or name.
2. Request a smaller page size (eg. less than the default 100)
3. Request less data, eg. the default `fields` value. (You don't say what your `fields` is currently set to.

I realise this is a bit indeterminate. That's just the way it is.